# Php, find out if the public folder is public_html or htdocs or www

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to find out what a public folder on the hosting is called? e.g. on some hosts its public_html, on others it's htdocs, others its simply www.

I'm, trying to write a script and I need to get this information to use later on.

e.g. I could use:

```
echo getcwd();
```

to get the full path but wondered if there is a way in php to just echo the public folder?

Comment: There might be multiple, or none at all. This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What use is that information to you?

Comment: Why should that be in any way relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to find out the public folder in system and it's give the only the path till the public folder.

Comment: Do you have checked with this solution?

Comment: Do you get chance to look into this?